# Angular 5: how to show return value from .ts to view

Tags: angular

In simple HTML and JS, the below code is working well.

**// main.js**

```
function videoHTML(videoNumber, trackName, trackType = 'srt') {
    return '<video id="video-js" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" ' +'controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" ' +'poster="img/' + videoNumber + '.jpg"' +
        'data-setup=\'{"example_option":true}\'>' +
        '<source src="videos/' + videoNumber + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" />' +
        '<track id="video-srt" kind="captions" src="subs/' + trackName + '.' + trackType + '" srclang="it" label="Italian" default></track>' +
        '</video>';
}
```

**// index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

But in Angular 5, how can I return the value from ts file to html view file? See below:

**// abc.component.ts**

```
function videoHTML(videoNumber, trackName, trackType = 'srt') {
        return '<video id="video-js" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" ' +'controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" ' +'poster="img/' + videoNumber + '.jpg"' +
            'data-setup=\'{"example_option":true}\'>' +
            '<source src="videos/' + videoNumber + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" />' +
            '<track id="video-srt" kind="captions" src="subs/' + trackName + '.' + trackType + '" srclang="it" label="Italian" default></track>' +
            '</video>';
    }
```

Comment: In angular you normally don't use functions that return html. You should use variables and binding. So in your component you could define a public variable that points to an object with the video variables. In your template html you can then refer to this variable & its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you clearly, you are trying to return a html string.. 
in angular 5, i'd suggest you bind it to a variable... 
so i'd rewrite your code as this..

**// abc.component.ts**

```
videoHTML:any;

getVideoHTML(videoNumber, trackName, trackType = 'srt') {
        this.videoHTML = '<video id="video-js" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" ' +'controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" ' +'poster="img/' + videoNumber + '.jpg"' +
            'data-setup=\'{"example_option":true}\'>' +
            '<source src="videos/' + videoNumber + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" />' +
            '<track id="video-srt" kind="captions" src="subs/' + trackName + '.' + trackType + '" srclang="it" label="Italian" default></track>' +
            '</video>';
    }
```

**then in your html file... 
**abc.component.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="videoHTML"></div>
```

that should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the ts file, you would have a variable for each parameter. and then you would have the full html file in the template file and do something like

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-hello-world",
  templateUrl: "./hello-world.html",
  styleUrls: ["./hello-world.css"]
})
export class HelloWorld implements OnInit {
  title = "Hello World";

  ngOnInit() {
  // do something on initialization
  }

}
```

and in the html file

```
<h1> Hello {{ title }} </h1>
```

and then every time the variable is changed in your code, the html will automatically update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding to `innerHtml` like `<div [innerHtml]="videoHTML(videoNumber, trackName)"></div>`. Or you can also assign it to a class field if you call function from elsewhere and bind that to innerHtml.
But why not use component for it instead? It would be more of angular way of doing it, which I strongly recommend.

**video.component.html**

```
<video id="video-js" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" [poster]="img/' + videoNumber + '.jpg" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source [src]="videos/' + videoNumber + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <track id="video-srt" kind="captions" [src]="subs/' + trackName + '.' + 
    trackType + '" srclang="it" label="Italian" default></track>
</video>
```

Where `videoNumber`, `trackName` and `trackType` would be your input bindings.